# UIScrollView doesn't scroll

Tags: swift, constraints, scrollview

I have a container view inside scroll view. The container view has other subviews. The scroll feature is not working. Please help

**UIScrollView and ContainerView**
Here the container view is inside the scrollview and ScrollView has constraint relative to safeAreaLayoutGuide

```
private let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
    let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: .zero)
    scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
    scrollView.backgroundColor = .systemRed
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return scrollView
}()

let containerView: UIView = {
    let containerView = UIView()
    return containerView
}()
```

viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.addSubview(containerView)
    scrollView.delegate = self
    containerView.addSubview(titleLabel)
    containerView.addSubview(overviewLabel)
    containerView.addSubview(downloadButton)
    containerView.addSubview(webView)
    applyConstraints()
}
```

Here are the constraints for the views:

```
func applyConstraints() {
    let scrollViewConstraints = [
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
        scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
        scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
        scrollView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
    ]
    let containerViewConstraints = [
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),
        scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
        scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor)
    ]
    let webViewConstraints = [
        webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 50),
        webView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        webView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        webView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400)
    ]
    let titleLabelConstraints = [
        titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: webView.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
        titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
    ]
    let overviewLabelConstraints = [
        overviewLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
        overviewLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
        overviewLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20)
    ]
    let downloadButtonConstraints = [
        downloadButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: overviewLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
        downloadButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        downloadButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 140),
        downloadButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)

    ]
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(scrollViewConstraints)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(containerViewConstraints)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(webViewConstraints)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(titleLabelConstraints)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(overviewLabelConstraints)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(downloadButtonConstraints)
}
```

I did try adjusting the content size and frame of the scrollview.

Comment: Not directly related to your issue but the following constraint should be removed: `scrollView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)`. You've already set the leading and trailing anchors. Also setting centerX is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Your scrollview constrains are set to itself. They need to be set to the containerView. Check the containerViewConstraints array.

Answer (score 0):

In containerViewContraints you're setting constraints for `scrollView` which should be set for `contrainerView`.

```
let containerViewConstraints = [
        containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
        containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),
        containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
        .trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor)
    ]
```

Add this line code to it changing above code does not work.

`containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true`

Comment: Setting the container view size to the scroll view size won't allow for any scrolling either since you just made the content size the same size as the scroll view size.

Comment: Yes it user provides full code so I can look on it seems like she has defined height but forgot to give containView bottomAnchor